# Calculation from visual table for power bi

Tags: mysql, powerbi, dax, powerquery, measure

Please help to sort this issue out.

- Source: Prime table. The date column used as prime date and base date separately. So user can compare the values between base date and prime date.
- Calendar table:
- Inactive calendar table: For base date

In visual table we have the measures such as "difference between base date & prime date" and the conditional string iteration based on the measures.

Issue: I just want to calculate how many “Same” or "Increase" there in the visual table for bar chart visualization purpose. Any measures or visuals not helping me because the following visual created from multiple tables and measures although it looks like simply.[Visual Table output from power bi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vihdM.png)

I couldn't get the count or sum of "SAME" instances.

1. Source [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ud0bU.png)
2. Expected output[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voOFP.png)
3. Intermediate table ( Visual table ) - need to create expected output from this table[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhTBF.png)

Comment: Where is the sample data and expected output?

Comment: Hey Peter, I added image of sources and expected output now

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)